# Get path of current middleware file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using NodeServices to run a JavaScript script within a middleware. However, the project that is using this, and where all of the JS files are stored, is separate from the startup project. Solution looks like this:

```
SolutionRoot/
  ├─Project/
  │ ├─NodeServices/
  | │ └─NodeService1/
  | │   └─adapter.js
  | ├─Middlewares/
  | | └─MyMiddleware.cs
  | └─Services/
  |   └─MyService/
  |    ├─MyService.cs
  |    └─IMyService.cs
  └─StartupProject/
    └─Startup.cs
```

For context, `Project` is an in-house CMS and `Startup` is a demo web project. `Project` is distributed through Nuget.

The issue I'm having is that I am registering NodeServices in the middleware file using an extension method on `IServiceCollection`. But regardless of what method I use, the path always comes out to be relative to `Startup/Startup.cs`. How can I get the path to the `MyMiddleware` file itself and pass that as an option to `NodeServices`? Or, more specifically, what is the best way to get an absolute path to the `NodeServices` folder, regardless of how this project is referenced (ie even if it was through a Nuget Package)?

**MyMiddleware.cs**

```
  public class MyMiddleware : IMiddleware {
    // ...
  }

  public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
  {
      public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
      {
          return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
      }

      public static IServiceCollection AddMyMiddleware(this IServiceCollection services)
      {
          var x = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // This returns the path to the startup, where it was called
          var path = "../Project/NodeServices"; // this works but not viable
          services.AddNodeServices(options => {
              options.ProjectPath = path;
          });

          services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
          services.AddTransient<MyMiddleware>();

          return services;
      }
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
namespace StartupProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Other Things
            services.AddMyMiddleware();
            // Other Things
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Other Things
            app.UseMyMiddleware();
            // Other Things
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What path should it return, for `MyMiddleware` when the application is compiled to a DLL or executable (IL)?

Comment: Honestly, I'm just looking for the best way to target the `NodeServices` folder.

Comment: What about using the `IWebHostEnvironment` service to retrieve the web root path, then `Path.Combine` to resolve the `NodeServices` folder path?

Comment: use Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); for your purpose. This returns the pathname where the currently executing assembly resides.

Comment: also if you have variable problem please check web.config and processPath , arguments and <environmentVariables> section to see if it defined corectly.